# How to fill out the PPP forgiveness loan application? What do I put for employee identifier, cash comp, and average fte?

Tags: united-states, loans, contractor, sba

Is employee identifier their ss#? And I'm not sure what to put for cash comp and average fte?

My ppp loan is for me, my wife, and 2 contractors. We run a repair shop and I only call in my contractors when I need specific things fixed and don't need them full time. As for me and my wife, we've been just withdrawing from the company bank account as needed. But now with the PPP program. I should write a check to me and her right? I was thinking of just writing 4 checks, one for each person and the rest will be used for rent. Does this work and in line with the forgiveness program or do i have to write 1 check for every week for 8 weeks?

I'm just unsure how to go about this PPP loan thing.

Answer (score 1):

Employer identifier is your "EIN" you use when you withhold your payroll taxes, etc.

Cash comp means cash compensation to your employees.

Average FTE means average "full time equivalent", so a full time employee is 1 whereas someone working 20 hours a week is 0.5 FTE.

EDIT: [here are the instructions](https://home.treasury.gov/system/files/136/3245-0407-SBA-Form-3508-PPP-Forgiveness-Application.pdf).